# Natural grading on quasi-homogenous ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

> Suppose $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$ is such that $f(\lambda^{q_1}x_1,..., \lambda^{q_n}x_n) = \lambda^df(x_1,..., x_n)$. Is there a natural grading on $\mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]/(f)$?

If $q_i = 1$ for all $i$ and $d = n$, then the answer is clearly yes, but is this true in general?

Comment: This is a guess.  There may be a homogeneous polynomial $g$ and positive integers $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n$ such that $g\left(x_1^{k_1},x_2^{k_2},\ldots,x_n^{k_n}\right)=f\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right)$.

Comment: Oops, that's not true.  This is a counterexample: $f(x,y,z)=\left(x^2-y\right)^2-z$.